# How to set pyhidapi library to search hidapi.dll in project folder?

Tags: python-3.x, ctypes, cx-freeze, hidapi

I'm trying to compile my application with cx_Freeze.

On development machine (with Windows 10) the program is working well. But when i try it on other machine (with Windows 7) I get an error message. Strange that when i try it on another machine with Windows 10 there was no error.

One of the libraries - "pyhidapi" - search hidapi.dll in some strange places.

```
C:\Users\***\Downloads\build>main
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\__startup__.py", line
 14, in run
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console.py", line 26,
 in run
  File "main.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "main.py", line 8, in main
  File "C:\ntt_flashcopier_source\interface\qt_interface.py", line 39, in __init
__
  File "C:\ntt_flashcopier_source\ntt_flash_copier\ntt_flash_copier.py", line 14
, in __init__
  File "C:\ntt_flashcopier_source\ntt_flash_copier\device_list\device_list.py",
line 11, in __init__
  File "C:\ntt_flashcopier_source\ntt_flash_copier\device_list\device_implemento
r_list.py", line 10, in __init__
  File "C:\ntt_flashcopier_source\ntt_flash_copier\device_list\hid_device_finder
.py", line 8, in __init__
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pyhidapi\pyhidapi.py", line 417, in hid_ini
t
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\pyhidapi\pyhidapi.py", line 162, in __load_
hidapi
RuntimeError: Could not find the hidapi shared library.
```

There is my setup.py file:

```py
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

executables = [
    Executable('main.py',
               icon='icon.ico')
]

_excludes = []
_include_files = ["hidapi.dll", 'conf.xml']
_includes = []

build_exe_options = {'include_msvcr': True,
                     'include_files': _include_files,
                     'includes': _includes,
                     'excludes': _excludes,
                     'build_exe': 'build',
                     }

setup(name='main',
      version='0.1',
      description='NTT Flash Copier',
      options={"build_exe": build_exe_options},
      executables=executables,
      requires=['pyhidapi', 'psutil', 'PyQt5']
      )
```

I expect this program to run on windows 7 and 10 without additional installations of something like python, etc. Simple saying the portable one.

**EDIT 1**:
Maybe the problem is in the system (Windows 7). I found out that cx_Freeze can't do multi-platform compiling. I will try to compile code in Windows 7 system tomorrow.

**EDIT 2**:
Done previous thing. It still get me the same issue and it don't work on other Windows 10 machine.

**EDIT 3**:
Now I'm trying to set virtualenv for my project. I got the same error. I think there must be the another way to install pyhidapi.

**EDIT 4**:
Tried to install pyhidapi from source. The error is still there. Now I'm rewriting code to implement pywinusb library. Do I need to answer this question or I will left it open, maybe someone answer it?

Comment: Did you look in the package? Is *hidapi.dll* there? does it have any dependencies? Also how did you conclude that "*search hidapi.dll in some strange places*"?

Comment: I looked, package has no hidapi.dll, but i include it in build directory.
About dependencies - i already don't know. There was nothing in docs, but they are poor. I'll try to check this, thank you.
"search hidapi.dll in some strange places": There is none C:\ntt_flashcopier_source\ on Windows 7 machine. This path is from the original Windows 10 machine.